# JSP Files in Class Diagrams

Tags: java, jsp, uml

I am making a web application with java and jsp and I need to draw the class diagram for the application, but since JSP files are not classes I think they are not supposed to be included in the class diagram, but in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733918/java-server-pages-jsp-files-in-uml-class-diagrams) it says that the JSP files are compiled as a subclass of `HttpServlet` and in the same thread some say yes and some say no, so should I include it in the class diagram? If so how should I include them?

Comment: JSP files are *compiled* into classes, but the class names are machine generated (thus I would not diagram them). Further, you probably should not be using JSP files any more. There are many, better, front-end Java HTML templating tools (for example JSF).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I was told to use jsp files by the client.. and also how would I represent the views if I do not show the jsp files, I'm stuck on the part where I connect the controller to the views in the UML

Comment: @marques you can do your design using the JSPs as views and the servlets as controllers.